# How to display value of inline formset in django admin change_form.html

Tags: python, django

I have 3 inline models in a Parent modelAdmin. I wish to display the value of a field 'contact' present in 1 of the inline models in the Parent ModelAdmin. In change_form.html of the django admin:

```
{% block inline_field_sets %}
{% for inline_admin_formset in inline_admin_formsets %}


    {% ifequal inline_admin_formset.formset.prefix 'client_executive' %}
    {{ inline_admin_formset.formset.form.contact }}
    {% endifequal%}

    {% include inline_admin_formset.opts.template %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

This does not show the value of the populated 'contact' value in the form in the template. The inline model has attribute extra=2. It displays nothing. What is the mistake? How can I access this value easily? Using django 1.6.5

Comment: Can you access the attribute from your Django app with regular Python code ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/1435290/e-nouri yes from the default django admin

Comment: Can you post the code that generates the object you trying to access its attributes ?

Comment: It is just the standard django model admin code which I wish to override

Answer (score 0):

yes you can do it. Easy than you think:

i wrote article about it

[inline in middle of change form](https://dev.to/danilovmy/django-admin-dynamic-inline-positioning-3cam)

in short terms:

1. add read only field "contact" in change form.
2. get inline, which you need, on render this new field "contact".
3. return render of this inline, don't forget to set only those fields in inline, which you want
4. Profit.

you need to add around 6 lines of code in you project

```
    admin.register(Product)
    class ProductModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
        inlines = (ImageAdminInline,)
        fields = ('title', 'image_inline', 'price')
        readonly_fields= ('image_inline',)  # we set the method as readonly field

        def image_inline(self, obj=None, *args, **kwargs):
            context = obj.response['context_data']
            inline = context['inline_admin_formset'] = context['inline_admin_formsets'].pop(0)
            return get_template(inline.opts.template).render(context, obj.request)

        def render_change_form(self, request, context, *args, **kwargs):
            instance = context['adminform'].form.instance  # get the model instance from modelform
            instance.request = request
            instance.response = super().render_change_form(request, context, *args, **kwargs)
            return instance.response
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you have a typo, in Django source I found this: `{% for inline_admin_form in inline_admin_formset %}` you have an additional 's' `{% for inline_admin_formset in inline_admin_formsets %}`